# Is it possible to type numbers or string or what ever in console more than for one calculation?

Tags: c

**Is it possible to type numbers or string or what ever in console more than once (more than for one calculation?)**
i mean if i let calculate sums and enter 2 digits, it'll give me an answer but the question is to ask the same opened console for 2 or 3 or more times to do the same operation without closing the console?

```
  #include <stdio.h> 
  main() 
  { 
      char ch; 
      printf("Enter a character\n"); 
      scanf("%c", &ch); 
      if (ch == \'a\' || ch == \'A\' || ch == \'e\' || ch == \'E\' || ch == \'i\' || ch == \'I\' || ch ==\'o\' || ch==\'O\' || ch == \'u\' || ch == \'U\') 
          printf("%c is a vowel.\n", ch); 
      else 
          printf("%c is not a vowel.\n", ch); 
      return 0; 
  }
```

for example here

Comment: sure, that's what loops and variables are for.

Comment: could u write an example of loops and variables?

Comment: Which book are you reading? I'm sure you can find the answer to this question fairly quickly in it...

Comment: im not attending the class btw ... ok nevermind.. thanks anyways

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Loop_%28computing%29#Loops http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variable_%28computer_science%29

Comment: Sorry, it just looks like you haven't really tried anything. Check out alk's links above to get an idea of how a loop works and what variables are. In your program, you can keep asking for input until some exit condition is reached (maybe the user enters a special character of some sort).

Comment: ok :) i think i should try hard but i was just interested if its possible at all. its possible right?

Comment: Yes -- it's definitely possible! Almost everything you can imagine is possible when you're programming. Check out the answer that was just posted to get some ideas.

Comment: @Giorgi - sure, I put it in the answer for you. There are lots of good resources online, check the link I posted in the answer for a few loop ideas. And in general I would invest in a good programming book, there's some suggestions if you click the `C` tag and go to the `info` page.

Comment: That's not valid C.  You should write: `if (ch == 'a' || ...)` without all the backslashes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unless I'm totally missing the point... What you're asking is the basic building blocks of programming. If you want to get user input to use later, you store it in variables; if you want to do the same things over and over again, you use loops:

```
int main()
{
    int a, b;
    char again = 'y';
    while(again == 'y'){        // loop until the user is done.
        printf("give me numbers\n");
        scanf("%d %d", &a, &b);
        printf("%d + %d = %d\n", a, b, a+b);
        printf("go again? (y/n)");
        scanf(" %c", &again);      // store the input from the user, should we do it again?
    }
    return 0;
}
```

So the output of such a program would be something like:

```
give me numbers
1 2
1 + 2 = 3
go again? (y/n)y
give me numbers
3 4
3 + 4 = 7
go again? (y/n)
```

That's one type of loop, there are lots of [looping constructs](http://www.cprogramming.com/tutorial/c/lesson3.html).

Comment: @GiorgiAzizGvimradze - happy to help. Looking at your program you posted I'd add two points. First this `ch == \'a\'` is not correct, you shouldn't be escaping those quotes just a check like `ch == 'a'` will do. Second if you wanted to loop that code without getting user input I would recommend a `for()` loop.